# ¿Porqué jquery plugin comienza por punto y coma?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin, jquery-plugins

Pues eso, he visto algunos plugins que comienzan igual como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
; // <-- esto de aquí es mi duda
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    // resto del código que no importa mucho
```

Mi pregunta es ¿porque ahí y para que sirve ponerlo ahí? no hay nada antes de ese `;` punto y coma.

Comment: Es común que en las aplicaciones ya producción todos los archivos JS ( y CSS) sean concatenados y minificados en uno solo, y como mecanismo para evitar errores de sintaxis al concatenar dos archivos es que se agregar dicho punto y coma (`;`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No se si estoy en lo cierto, pero mi logica me dice, que lo que está haciendo es terminar una sentencia de un archivo de `script` anterior a ese, es decir, si tienes un archivo `script` anterior a jquery en tu html y tienes un codigo y no le pones el `;`, jquery se asegura que así sea.

> El código no revienta si tiene 2 puntos y comas (`;;`)

Ejemplo:

```
// 1 archivo script
document.write("Hola mundo") // no finaliza con ;

// archivo jquery
; // <-- esto de aquí es mi duda
(function($, window, document, undefined) {
// resto del código que no importa mucho
```

Esto tampoco causa error

```
document.ready("Hola mundo")
;
/* Código ... */
```

Si lo ves?

Comment: Es algo como un método de prevención en caso que un `script` anterior no use punto y coma?

Comment: Si exactamente, y parece descabellado porq javascript actualmente funciona y corre bien sin que le pongas el punto y coma. Pero lo que no se, es si los navegadores de versiones antiguas soporten el que no le pongas el punto y coma.